# React Widget text too small

Tags: css, reactjs, widget

Hi I have built a widget using react and embedded this onto a another website.

However the third party site has the following css `font-size: 62.5%;` on the `<html>` tag. Which is reducing size of the fonts.

I can not work out a way to over ride this, if I add `font-size: 100%;` or even `font-size: 100% important;` on to widget wrapper
`<div id="wrapper">` I can see the css is there when inspect the element but the font size does not change, it is still set to the 62.5%

Comment: you mean `font-size: 100% !important;` not just `important` ?

Comment: @Usama yeah that's right

Comment: instead of `%` try other unit like `rem`. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9sfgxtdy/2/) example

Comment: Thanks, that's still not making a difference. I wonder if my css is loading in too late.

Comment: Can't figure out the reason, you can try changing browser or doing hard refresh in chrome using `CTRL + F5`

Comment: What's infesting if I inspect the css and look at the computed style is working out as 16px although it is not displaying as such.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245624/discussion-between-usama-and-mrspop88).

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix I am confident with but managed to work round this by simply targeting the

inside the  #wrapper